# How to apply CSS / Styling to imported joint js bpmn objects?

Tags: javascript, css, json, jointjs

We have recently integrated parts of our dashboard with a company that provides us with Business Process Model And Notation (BPMN) json objects.

We import the BPMN json object with "fromJSON()" onto the joint.dia.Paper.

And that works fine.

By I cannot figure out how to style that object? How can I apply CSS or any other form of styling to my imported object?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

**This will work for Rappid 2.0:**

CSS should works fine, e.g

```
<style>
    .joint-theme-bpmn[data-type='bpmn.Event'] circle {
        stroke: red;
    }
</style>
```

where `data-type` corresponds with property `type` on particular element:

```
    joint.shapes.bpmn.Event = joint.dia.Element.extend({

        // ... markup ... 

        defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
            type: 'bpmn.Event',
            // attrs: {
            // ...
```

**For 1.x versions:**

instead of attribute `data-type` there is an class name without `.`, so for the `bpmn.Event` type you can find something like

`<g id="j_46" model-id="083..." class="element bpmn Gateway" ">...</g>`

then CSS like this should be working:

```
 <style>
        .bpmn.Event circle {
            stroke: red;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Looking at the bpmn object (with console.dir or Chromes developer tools) there is no data-types wihtin the bpmn object? Is the "bpmn.Event" a general identification or a specific object? The same question goes for "circle" - is that a specific object?
Could you please make an example for targeting changing the background for the Pool bpmn object?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: 'circle' is a part of 'bpmn.Event' shape, check the output in DOM. For 'bpmn.Pool' it should be CSS e.g. '.bpmn.Pool rect {stroke: red; }'